# Can air trapped in a water line controlled by solenoid cause a slow drip?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, applied-mechanics

I have a water dispenser on a fridge, that has started dripping after replacing a filter, and turning off slowly. The manufacturer says that this might be due to air trapped in the line.

I can't imagine how this could be. In this case, the solenoid is either open or it isn't. Is it possible for air such a simple system to affect the behaviour of the solenoid? Or to do anything that could manifest as dripping?

Comment: if the trapped air is between the valve and the exit spout, then the air volume will increase when atmospheric pressure decreases, causing water to drip out of the spout